# Error al editar debe ser tipo cadena matriz dada laravel 9 htmlspecialchars(): Argumento #1 ($cadena) debe ser de tipo cadena, matriz dada

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

Estoy tratando de editar un formulario que estoy realizando pero siempre me da ese error, estoy utilizando laravel 9

Aca mi modelo

```
class Documento extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
  protected $fillable = [
    'sigla',
    'nombre',
    'orden',

  ];

  protected $primaryKey = 'idtipodocumento';
}
```

protected $primaryKey = 'idtipodocumento';
}

Este es mi controlador

```
public function edit($idtipodocumento)
  {
    $documento = Documento::find($idtipodocumento);
    return view('documentos.editar', compact('documento'));
  }
```

Este es mi vista index

```
 @foreach ($documentos as $documento)
          <tr>
       <td style="display: none;">{{ $documento->idtipodocumento }}</td>
       <td>{{ $documento->sigla }}</td>
       <td>{{ $documento->nombre }}</td>
       <td>{{ $documento->orden }}</td>
         </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Esta la vista editar que es la que no me funciona

```
 {!! Form::model($documento, [
                                'method' => 'PATCH',
                                'route' => ['documentos.update', $documento->idtipodocumento],
                            ]) !!}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Sigla*</label>
                                        {!! Form::text('sigla', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Nombre*</label>
                                        {!! Form::text('nombre', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Orden*</label>
                                        {!! Form::number('orden', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Este es mi Update de mi controlador, no estoy seguro pero creo que ahi es donde esta el problema

```
    public function update(Request $request, $idtipodocumento)
  {
    notify()->preset('error', ['title' => 'Error']);
    $this->validate($request, [

      'sigla' => 'required',
      'nombre' => 'required',
      'orden' => 'required',


    ]);

    $documento = Documento::find($idtipodocumento);


    notify()->preset('editar', ['title' => 'Bien Hecho']);
    return redirect()->route('documentos.index');
  }
```

Ya he intentado de varias formas dar solución al error pero aun no doy con el, les agradezco su ayuda muchas gracias

Comment: lee [ask], el codigo se agrega con formato de texto NO COMO IMAGEN.

Comment: @Emerson Machado serviría de mucho que nos compartas el error que recibes tal y como aparezca, sin traducir. Además, ¿el error lo recibes al presionar el botón "Guardar"? Si es así, entonces necesitamos tu método `update()` en lugar del `edit()`.

Comment: @JonatanLavado Listo ya edite y agregue el update()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente el error está en estas líneas de código:

```
{!! Form::text('sigla', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Dado que `Form::text()` recibe un valor por defecto como segundo parámetro y le estás pasando un array. Por eso obtienes el siguiente error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Por ende, si no quieres asignar un valor por defecto, debes especificarlo pasando `null` como segundo parámetro.

```
{!! Form::text('sigla', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

De igual forma, estás usando `Laravel 9` en tu proyecto, sin embargo este tipo de formularios se usaba en `Laravel 4`, deberías considerar migrarlos.

Comment: Ya realice lo que dices y aun sigue dando el mismo error, cabe recalcar que sigla trae ya unos valores directamente de la base de datos, ¿ Como lo harias en un formulario de laravel 9?

Comment: El cambio tienes que hacerlo en todos los elementos, no solamente en el que te puse como ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya funciona, ahora  `{!! Form::text('sigla', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`  sigla es un arreglo, como haria para traermelo?